# Silverstripe 3.1.x getting values from Parent

Tags: content-management-system, silverstripe

I would like to get a generic function working for getting Data in Template of a Page and if the property is not set, getting it from the Parent or Parents Parent and so on. With generic I mean independent of Relations like db, HasOne, HasMany, ManyMany. Let's say I have this for ManyMany but would like to detect if it's a Object, HasManyList or ManyManyList or a value. Is anything like this built in or how would you go about?

```
function ManyManyUpUntilHit($ComponentName){
  $Component = $this->getManyManyComponents($ComponentName);
  if($Component && $Component->exists())
  return $Component;
  $Parent = $this->Parent();
  if(is_object($Parent) && $Parent->ID != 0){
    return $Parent->ManyManyUpUntilHit($ComponentName);
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

in template:

```
$ManyManyUpUntilHit(Teaser)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no in built method to do this in Silverstripe. You will need to write your own function to do this.

Here is an example to get a page's has_one, has_many or  many_many resource by parameter, or go up the site tree until a resource is found, or we hit a root page:

```php
function getComponentRecursive($componentName) {

    // has_one
    if ($this->has_one($componentName)) {
        $component = $this->getComponent($componentName);
        if (isset($component) && $component->ID)
        {
            return $component;
        }
    }

    // has_many
    if ($this->has_many($componentName)) {
        $components = $this->getComponents($componentName);
        if (isset($components) && $components->count())
        {
            return $components;
        }
    }

    // many_many
    if ($this->many_many($componentName)) {
        $components = $this->getManyManyComponents($componentName);
        if (isset($components) && $components->count())
        {
            return $components;
        }
    }

    if ($this->ParentID != 0)
    {   
        return $this->Parent()->getComponentRecursive($componentName);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: If I get this right, this solves the problem in a even less generic manner than the function above, since you have to specify "Resources" in php. What I would like to have, is a function that allows me to specify the Resource in Template regardless if it's a DB, HasOne, HasMany or ManyMany Resource.

Comment: I misunderstood before. I've updated my answer to work using a parameter and work for has_one, has_many or many_many. I've tested has_one but not the others. I'm not sure how to get items from db, belongs_to or belongs_many_many.

Comment: sorry it took me way to long to come back to this. a.t.m. I do not have a usecase from the belonging-side so it works great for me - thank you!