# Adding a widget to all blog entries (using the blog module)

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am trying to add the same widgets to ALL of the blog entry pages. Perhaps add them to the blog holder page and inherit them on all blog entry pages. I want the widgets to be automatically assigned to all blog entry pages without having to manually add the widgets.

Is there a method to pull from parent, or is there a way built into the blog module to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how widgets work since I do not use theme. If it's saved in a relation something like the following could help you out.
[Silverstripe 3.1.x getting values from Parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19955973/silverstripe-3-1-x-getting-values-from-parent)
or as a Extension/Decorator
https://gist.github.com/lerni/1e046af2005494636707

Answer (score -2):

I believe that is standard (default) behaviour.
As you say, add them to the Holder page, then set blog pages to inherit (default I believe).

Comment: I have tried adding a widget area to the blog entry page while there are widgets assigned to the blog holder page. The widget will be on the blog holder page but fails to carry over to the child blog entry pages.